# Herepy EVCharging Station API; Error occured: Forbidden, description: These credentials do not authorize access

Tags: python, here-api, herepy

I am trying to use HERE api to get some charging station data. I signed up for a freemium account and verified my email address.

I am using `Herepy` to send requests but unfortunately I get the following error

```
HEREError: Error occured: Forbidden, description: These credentials do not authorize access
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error.
I got my API key under the section `Get your credentials` ; subsection  `REST` and generated the API key.
I am using the following script to test my request

```
from herepy import *
import requests
api_key = "MY_API_KEY"  # Enter your key here
evAPI = EVChargingStationsApi(api_key)
response = evAPI.get_stations_circular_search(latitude = 37.87166, longitude = -122.2727, radius = 10000)
```

but I get the following error
[image]

Comment: Please share the api documentation you are referring to.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport this is the EV charging station documentation I followed https://herepy.abdullahselek.com/api/ev_charging_stations_api/

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport also can you please confirm if freemium users get access to EV Charging API? I've got a user on another thread saying that it's not available in freemium plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EV Charging Station API is not available to freemium customers yet.

Comment: Is this still the case?